# How to implement a 'mark message as read' inbox rule with mutt

Tags: mutt

I get a lot automated e-mail alerts, and I would like to be able to configure mutt to remove the new message flag (`N`) from new messages received from specific senders. Basically, I don't want to have to manually press 'N' on hundreds of auto-generated messages in my inbox, so the `N` flag will be meaningful again.

My intuition tells me to use `message-hook` in the `.muttrc` file, and this is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
 message-hook '~f \"automation-account@domain.com\"' 'push "N"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `message-hook` would only apply when you go to view a message which matches the pattern.  Once you do that, the **N** flag would be removed automatically so that isn't likely to be helpful.  Mutt doesn't have support for modifying messages as they come in, that would need to be done by whatever you have that delivers messages into your mailbox.

The closest that you could come in mutt would be to use a macro or folder hook to execute the commands to tag matching messages and then remove the new flag.  Something like:

```
macro index G "<tag-prefix-cond><tag-message><end-cond><tag-pattern>~f automation-account@domain.com\n<tag-prefix-cond><clear-flag>N"
```

The part before `<tag-pattern>` is to ensure that it doesn't apply to any messages which had previously been tagged.

A similar command string could be used with the `push` command in a `folder-hook` to automatically do that when you first open a folder.